# File id in Hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to store some information of the files being processed from HDFS. What would be the most suitable way to read a file location and byte offset in a java program of a file stored in HDFS?

Is there concept of a unique file id being associated to each file stored in Hadoop 1? 
If yes, then how can it be fetched in a MapReduce program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding,
You can use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` class for all your needs.
1.You can get each file uniquely identified with it's URI or you can use `getFileChecksum(Path path)`
2.You can get all files all block locations with the `getFileBlockLocations(FileStatus file,long  start,long len)`
`TextInputFormat` gives byte offset for key starting location in the file, which is not same as the file offset on the HDFS.
You can use the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` class to fulfill all your needs. There are many other methods available. Please go through it for better understanding.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to "The Definitive Guide to Hadoop", the input format TextInputFormat gives to the key a value of the byte offset.

For the filename you can look into these:

[Mapper input Key-Value pair in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624607/mapper-input-key-value-pair-in-hadoop)

[How can to get the filename from a streaming mapreduce job in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915569/how-can-to-get-the-filename-from-a-streaming-mapreduce-job-in-r)